# jQuery does not allow me to create new elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a new button using jQuery for each iteration of my for loop but for some reason my buttons do not render on the page. Though I'm new to all this, I do not think that I have made a mistake with my syntax but for some strange reason jQuery does not allow me to create elements and I couldn't find any explanation for that. It could be something stupid on my side and I appreciate if you guys take a look at this snippet of my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong:

```
for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        const letterBtn = $("<button>");
        letterBtn.addClass("letter-button letter letter-button-color");
        letterBtn.attr("data-letter", letters[i]);
        letterBtn.text(letters[i]);
        $("#button").append(letterBtn);
      }
```

Here is my full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fridge Magnets</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background: url(assets/fridge.png) no-repeat;
  }

  .letter {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 2px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
  }

  .letter-button-color {
    color: darkcyan;
  }

  .fridge-color {
    color: orange;
  }

  #display {
    margin-top: 78px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }

  #buttons {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }

  #clear {
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="display"></div>
  <div id="buttons"></div>
  <button id="clear">clear</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


      const letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "_"];

      for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        const letterBtn = $("<button>");
        letterBtn.addClass("letter-button letter letter-button-color");
        letterBtn.attr("data-letter", letters[i]);
        letterBtn.text(letters[i]);
        $("#button").append(letterBtn);
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide your html part also

Comment: Your error is $("#button").append(letterBtn); there is no element with id button. It seems that you want $("#buttons").append(letterBtn);

Comment: @TomaszBucko thank you so much for pointing that out... You are right... such stupid newbie mistake... thanks a lot

Comment: :) please up vote me... :-D

Comment: I did mate... and thanks again for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following example.

```
let letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for (let i = 0;i < letters.length;i++) {
    let newBtn = $('<button>')
    newBtn.addClass("letter-button letter letter-button-color");
    newBtn.attr("data-letter", letters[i]);
    newBtn.text(letters[i])
    $('#mainbar').append(newBtn) // #mainbar means your target element that will include new buttons
}
```

Comment: Your ocde works perfectly... but what's the difference between this and my code? I'd really appreciate if you can explain that cause I see both are essentially the same or maybe I'm missing a detail here

Comment: please check my comment part of sample code, your mistake is to use incorrect target selector where new buttons will be placed.